# Getting file path while opening winform app from context menu.

Tags: c#

I cant seem to get the correct file path when opening a file with my winform app from the right click menu. I would like to be able to right click a text file, run my program (c:\MyApp %1 in the regedit.exe) and have the file path appear in a message box before the program opens. Right now all I seem to get is the file path of my actual program. This is what I have so far.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {   
       string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(); 
       foreach (string arg in args)
       {
          MessageBox.Show(arg);
       }
       InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I understand this is probably an easy fix but I am very new at this and might be missing something obvious.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have only 1 msgbox with name of your program? Can you check if it's not your registry entry error? For example by running your application with any argument from console: app.exe test?

Comment: Yeah one msgbox appears with the program path. I placed it under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -> txtfile -> shell -> "MyCommandName" -> command -> c:\MyApp %1. Seems to work fine.

Comment: You should have 1 default value in command like this: "C:\MyApp.exe" "%1". Do not ignore "'s. And your program should print 2 message boxes one after another. Name of the program, when you ok it - name of the file.

Comment: Added the quotations and I am still only getting the one messagebox with my program path.

Comment: I've checked that on my machine and it works ok. The only thing that comes to my mind is to check length of GetCommandLineArgs() - its normal that 1st arg is a path to exe file. However, if you are running it with a parameter, you should get it as a 2nd element in array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this info will help, since it sounds like you've checked all this, but I ran this quick test just now and it works:
First, the registry settings should look like this. If you don't have quotes around the %1, and it's a long filename such as "New Text Document.txt", each word will become a separate argument, so be sure to put quotes around the "%1".
[image: Registry settings]

Assuming the registry is set up correctly, you should now see your new command when you right-click on a text file:
[image: Right-click menu]

When your program runs, the first item in the array, which is args[0], will be the path to EXE. The second item, which is args[1], should be the name of the file.
If you added the line
MessageBox.Show(args[1])

you should see the name of the file in its entirety when you run via the right-click. If you get an error saying "Index was outside the bounds of the array" then it definitely didn't get the argument.
One way to test that the program is working correctly is to open a DOS prompt and type the path to the program like this and hit enter:
c:\MyApp.exe "This line should appear"
This bypasses the registry and tests the program directly. If this works, then you know the issue isn't with the program itself but rather with the registry setting. If this doesn't work, then there's still some issue with the C# code.